# Generating Variables to be something

Tags: batch-file

I want to automate the process of 50 times typing: set x%x%y%y%=.
To do this i created a simple loop, the only problem is it won't output anything.
I tried searching it up online, but without success.

Here is what i already tried:

```
@echo off

set x=0
set y=0

:Generate
set location=x%x%y%y%
set x%x%y%y%=.
if "%x%" GTR "9" (if "%x%" GTR "3" (goto S)) else (goto Generate)

:S
echo %x1y4%%x2y4%%x3y4%%x4y4%%x5y4%%x6y4%%x7y4%%x8y4%%x9y4%%x10y4%
echo %x1y3%%x2y3%%x3y3%%x4y3%%x5y3%%x6y3%%x7y3%%x8y3%%x9y3%%x10y3%
echo %x1y2%%x2y2%%x3y2%%x4y2%%x5y2%%x6y2%%x7y2%%x8y2%%x9y2%%x10y2%
echo %x1y1%%x2y1%%x3y1%%x4y1%%x5y1%%x6y1%%x7y1%%x8y1%%x9y1%%x10y1%

pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact you never increase the `x` or `y`variables?

Comment: `for /L %%x in (1,1,10) do for /L %%y in (1,1,4) do set "x%%xy%%y=."`